# No matching function for call to default constructor

Tags: c++

The related code is listed below.Why the compiler complains "'B::B()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed"? This is the first question in my mind.I find a hint soon.The compiler says:"no matching function for call to 'A::A()'".

**My question is that why there should be a matching function for call to 'A::A()' in class B.** I would be grateful to have some help to this question.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int x;
    A(int x): x(x) {std::cout << "A:A(int)" <<x << std::endl;} 
};

struct B: A
{
};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

The error messages:

```
    <source>: In function 'int main()':

    <source>:17:7: error: use of deleted function 'B::B()'

       17 |     B b;

          |       ^

    <source>:11:8: note: 'B::B()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:

       11 | struct B: A

          |        ^

    <source>:11:8: error: no matching function for call to 'A::A()'

    <source>:8:5: note: candidate: 'A::A(int)'

        8 |     A(int x): x(x) {std::cout << "A:A(int x=1)" <<x << std::endl;} // user-defined default constructor

          |     ^

    <source>:8:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

    <source>:5:8: note: candidate: 'constexpr A::A(const A&)'
    > Blockquote
```

Comment: How would `B` know how to initialize its `A` component?

Comment: Could you please explain that in more detail?Do you mean there should be constructors with the same signature in both base class and the derived class?

Comment: Thank you.I understand the relationship.But i am poor at C++.As the examples in the answers, it seems that  the constructors does not need to be the same in both base class and the derived class

Comment: The derived type's constructor needs to call a constructor for each type it inherits from. That isn't a problem when the inherited type has a default constructor. It uses that one. But since `A` does not have a default constructor, you need to specify which one and with what arguments. The linked duplicate should explain this in more details.

Comment: What do you mean by "The derived type's constructor needs to call a constructor for each type it inherits from."?

Comment: `B` is composed of an `A`. To initialize a `B` you need to initialize all of it's components, including the inherited `A`. So, in every `B` constructor you need to call a `A` constructor in the member initializer list (as shown in the answers below). Normally, if you don't, it just calls the default constructor by default. Since `A` doesn't have one, you *must* specify the constructor to use.

Comment: With your help,I completly comprehend it now.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is not able to generate a default constructor for B because the constructor of B needs to call the constructor of A. The constructor of A expects an int and the compiler does not know what value to pass to it. This means you need to declare a constructor of B yourself that takes care of this.

You can either have the constructor of B also take an int and use that or for example have B use a fixed value instead:

```
struct B: A
{
    B() : A(10) {}

    B(int x) : A(x) {}
};
```

But you have to pass something to A's constructor.

Comment: As the example in your answer, to remove the complie error, it seems that the signatures of the constructors does not need to be the same in both base class and the derived class.Am i right?

Comment: @steve There is no requirement that the base type and the derived type have similar constructors. You just have to be sure that it is possible to call one of the base type's constructors with the information available in the derived type's constructor.

Comment: I see.You make it clear to me.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because of the parent child relationship that comes with inheritance. You cannot create a child without creating the parent. The parent class `A` has a non-default constructor taking a parameter. You need to call that constructor through class B in its constructor like this:

```
struct B: A
{
    // example
    B() : A(3) {}
};
```